# getpeername always gives bad file descriptor

Tags: c, sockets, trace

I have the following code, that i am trying to use to get the address of the other end of the socket, but `getpeername()` always fails with `bad file descriptor` error. What am i doing wrong?

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include<syscall.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/ptrace.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/user.h>
#include<sys/syscall.h>   /* For SYS_write etc */
#include<stdlib.h>

#define ORIG_RAX 15
#define SYSCALL_MAXARGS 6
#define RDI 14

int main()
{
    //**********declarations and memory allocations**********//
    ssize_t size;
    long sys_call_number, temp_long;
    int status, temp, i, j, k, flag;

    struct sockaddr_in ip_addr_struct;
    socklen_t ip_addr_structlen = sizeof(ip_addr_struct);
    struct user_regs_struct regs;

    struct sockaddr_in* connect_struct;

    char* filepath = malloc(1024);
    char* fdpath = malloc(1024);
    char* message = malloc(1024);
    char* connect_ip = malloc(1024); 
    char* ip_addr = malloc(1024);

    char* temp_char1,* temp_char2;

    pid_t proc;

    //**********getting pid and attaching to process**********//
    scanf("%d",&proc);

    ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH,proc, NULL, NULL);

    //**********starting the trace process**********//

    //The system call number used in switch() case to determine particular system   calls// 
    while(1)
    {
            wait(&status);
            if(WIFEXITED(status))
            {
                printf("****Process exited****\n");
                break;
            }
                ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, proc, NULL, &regs);
                sys_call_number = regs.orig_rax;

        switch(sys_call_number)
        {
            case 44:
                printf("sendto\n");
                //***printing the register values containing system call parameters***//
                printf("%llu - %llu - %llu - %llu - %llu - %llu\n", regs.rdi, regs.rsi, regs.rdx, regs.r10, regs.r8, regs.r9);
                //***getting the peer address***//
                errno = 0;
                temp = getpeername(regs.rdi, (struct sockaddr *)&ip_addr_struct, &ip_addr_structlen);
                if(temp == -1)
                {
                    printf("error is getpeername-%d-%s\n",temp,strerror(errno));
                    return -1;
                }

                int port = ntohs(ip_addr_struct.sin_port);
                inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(ip_addr_struct.sin_addr), ip_addr, 1024);
                printf("%d-%s\n", port, ip_addr);
                port = 0;
                //***reading message being send***//
                temp_char2 = message;
                j = 0;
                while( j < (regs.rdx/8) )
                {
                    temp_long = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, proc, regs.rsi + (j*8) , NULL);
                    memcpy(temp_char2, &temp_long, 8);
                    temp_char2 += 8;
                    ++j;
                }
                temp_long = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, proc, regs.rsi + (j*8) , NULL);
                memcpy(temp_char2, &temp_long, regs.rdx - (j*8) );
                message[regs.rdx] = '\0';
                printf("Message-%s-\n\n", message);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output from one such system call

```
sendto
14 - 32064144 - 884 - 16384 - 0 - 0
--1-Bad file descriptor
0-0.0.0.0
Message-GET /?gfe_rd=cr&ei=2WYzVLCjFq7M8gfLlICoDg HTTP/1.1^M
User-Agent: NetSurf/2.9 (Linux; x86_64)^M
Host: www.google.co.in^M
Accept: */
Accept-Encoding: gzip^M
 Cookie:PREF=ID=yu3vtr7i452389b4o236v4t28o37v723tn8vt0783tnv0723p78 N823748923bt87t2387b473287b8273t48
```

Comment: @nos: but the following code prints the write `http header` when the `sendto()` system call is executed, how can the file descriptor be invalid??
i will post some output

Comment: Whatever file descriptor the other process you're ptrace'ing is using, isn't valid in your program, thus the bad file descriptor. 

Also if the socket that the other program is sending is an UDP socket which is not connect()'ed, getpeername() wouldn't give you any info in any case.

Comment: @nos: how shall i try for a UDP socket?

Comment: Your program did not open(), call socket() or otherwise create the file descriptor. The file descriptor is not associated with your program. If the program is using sendto() and specifies the destination address, you can probably find that destination address in some of the arguments of the sendto() call.

Comment: @nos: dude i am attaching to a process that is creating the sockets and all using ptrace, and then getting the parameter values of those system calls from the registers `regs.rdi` and all

Comment: @nos: but i used the same way to get `filenames` from the `read()` `write()` system calls

Comment: @nos: ya, and then i did a `readlink()` on them

Comment: @nos: i know this way of getting the ip address, but this is kind of a lengthy process looking into `tcp` and `udp` file and searching for a match, the process i am attached to gets suspended every time i try to read the values of its system calls. i cant afford a complex method to get the ip address..

Comment: @nos: i got your point, why it is not working.. `getpeername()` looks into the `fd`s of its own process, and since `regs.rdi` number belongs to the other process to which i am attached, it gives `bad file descriptor`.. 

But i am curious, trying to find a way to use  `getpeername` in this scenario

Comment: @haris Why? It's pointless. There is no scenario here to be interested in. Unless the socket is connected there is no result, and unless the socket was created by your process you can't do anything with it at all.

Comment: @EJP: i am actually trying to intercept all system calls made by that process and try to detect any malicious activity that occurs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

socket descriptor is not shared between two processes. the captured socket descriptor is only effective in the traced process, and not effective in the tracer process. that's why `getpeername` complains bad descriptor. 
from the manual of `ptrace`:
The ptrace() system call provides a means by which a parent process may observe and control the execution of another process, and  examine  and change its core image and registers.  It is primarily used to implement breakpoint debugging and system call tracing. 
there's no word says they share process space, thus, they can not share socket descriptors, memory address, etc..